# Am I being too detailed with my questions?

Tags: discussion, markdown, feedback

**The Problem**

I've posted a few questions on Stack Overflow recently that haven't got many views or answers. I'm trying to identify why that is.

I've provided lots of detail in [my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847937/how-can-i-make-my-app-more-responsive) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954238/why-is-my-app-crashing-when-i-modify-a-core-data-relationship-in-an-nsoperation-s), and I've stated what I want to achieve as well as my specific problem. I've also [read this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60057/details-to-specify-when-asking-questions).

I'm starting to think I'm being *too* detailed in my question and that's putting people off.
Of course, it could just be that my questions are so narrow in scope and specific that no-one has an answer for me.

**My Question**

Am I being too detailed in my questions? Or is what I'm doing total information overload?

Should I make them briefer, easier to scan and have more of a "progressive reveal" so that as I get responses I reveal more detail about my issue?

I'd really appreciate any feedback people have on the formatting and style of my questions.

**Update**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954238/why-is-my-app-crashing-when-i-modify-a-core-data-relationship-in-an-nsoperation-s) has had three upvotes so far, so I guess in this case I must be doing something right. I'll leave it for a few days and see if I get any answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do *not* intentionally engage in a progressive reveal please. I find that strategy rude. It comes down to *"I'm going to ask the wrong question in hopes of trapping an audience for the right questions."*.

Looking at your questions I see

- They are addressed to a medium-small community on Stack Overflow. I feel your pain on that but it does mean they will take longer to get answer
- That is **a lot** of information. You're probably suffering a lot of "tl;dr" If you can isolate the problem--even a little bit--you may get a better response.

Comment: All great points. You confirm what I instinctively feel - my questions have too much information, but I should find ways of being more succinct, not deleting vital parts of my question. I feel like I have isolated the problem as much as I can in my most recent question, but in other questions, maybe I'm being a bit too general. Thanks!